# Is there a way to access files in "Google Chrome" folder via Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

The "Google Chrome" folder stores Chrome synchronous information such as bookmarks. I was just wondering if there is a way to access those information via the Google Docs API?
I've look at the demo provided by Google but it doesn't seem you can access that folder via API. The demo that I looked is [here](http://doclistmanager.googlecodesamples.com/), if you click "Folders", it returns all the folders I have(including all subfolders) but just not the "Google Chrome" folder.

Also, any ideas what format are the bookmarks stored in "Google Chrome --> Bookmarks" folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Chrome folder isn't accessible at the moment via Docs API. This problem has already been issued:
http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1822

Sorry if this wasn't the answer you were looking for. However, this feature could be implemented in a future, so stay alert.